# Built-in spell checker not working in Wordpress 3.3.1

Tags: editor

I am using WP 3.3.1 and have noticed that the built-in spell checker (ABC button) does not work, even when there are mis-spelt words.

I have read a number of forum posts that essentially recommend using a standalone plugin to handle spell checking, however is there a fix for the built-in spell checker?

Or am I resigned to installing another plugin?

Comment: 3.3.1? This is dead.

Comment: You should upgrade away from WordPress 3.3.1 to 3.7.1. There are security fixes that you need, and many other changes to improve speed and reliability as well.

Answer (score 1):

Built in spell checker was always a bad idea especially since it relies on external services that might not support the actual language you are writing in. In addition those services might have changed their API since the days of 3.3.1 in a way that is no longer compatible with the 3.3.1 code.

> Or am I resigned to installing another plugin?

IMO spell checking for 99% of the sites should be done as a browser plugin. The exception is when you have several writers and you want to force uniformity, but then you probably want to host your own dictionary, and will need a plugin for that.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going for the AfterTheDeadline plugin which works with 3.3.1. http://wordpress.org/plugins/after-the-deadline/